# Calling Backend from React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react-redux application which contains a table component which presents data and a filter component which filters the data via a drop-down list. I need to change my app so that I can receive data form the backend each time a selection is made using the drop-down. I have the following:  components, reducers, action creators, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. In which should I call the backend?

Comment: You could call it from your `action creators` or `component` itself.. or any other method/place you can think of., I wouldn't recommend calling it from **`reducers`**, `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: Take a look at redux-thunk library. What it will do, is allow you to write action creators which return functions, and when calling those action creators, it will also call the function and pass redux dispatch method.

You can then use mapDispatchToProps middleware, to pass those action creators via props, and you can call them from your components. You can then make an action for retrieval event, which can be dispatched in the callback of your request to backend. Reducer will then handle putting data from that action into store, and when props update you have updated data in your component.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a redux midleware for expose an api client in your actions.

My redux midleware:

```
export default function clientMiddleware(client) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState);
    }

    const { promise, types, ...rest } = action; // eslint-disable-line no-redeclare
    if (!promise) {
      return next(action);
    }

    const [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = types;
    next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST });

    const { auth } = getState();

    client.setJwtToken(auth.token || null);

    const actionPromise = promise(client, dispatch);
    actionPromise.then(
      result => next({ ...rest, result, type: SUCCESS }),
      error => next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE })
    ).catch((error) => {
      console.error('MIDDLEWARE ERROR:', error);
      next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE });
    });

    return actionPromise;
  };
}
```

Its use in an action:

```
const SAVE = 'redux-example/widgets/SAVE';
const SAVE_SUCCESS = 'redux-example/widgets/SAVE_SUCCESS';
const SAVE_FAIL = 'redux-example/widgets/SAVE_FAIL';

export function save(widget) {
  return {
    types: [SAVE, SAVE_SUCCESS, SAVE_FAIL],
    id: widget.id, // additionnal data for reducer
    promise: client => client.post('/widget/update', {
      data: widget
    })
  };
}

// in reducer:
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE:
      return state;
    case SAVE_SUCCESS:
      // you can use action.result and action.id here
      return state;
    case SAVE_FAIL:
      // and you can use action.error and action.id here
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Finally, you must pass this action to your component with mapDispatchToProps.

Hoping to have helped you

Answer (score 0):

I use the redux-api-middleware https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware
Based on Dan Abramov's example.